# Find efficient algorithm to compute smallest index k such that $|f(k)-v|$ is minimum

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, minimum, minimization

**Problem:** Given a function f which is increasing, a float v and a positive integer n, find an integerk in the interval [0, n) such that |f(k)-v| is minimum. Use the fact that f is increasing!

My idea is to consider the first k such that f(k) >= v, since after that we don't have to check, since the function is increasing. That should return the index where the minimum of f lies.

However, when i implemented the code, it returned the wrong answer in certain cases. Here is the code:

```
def f(x):
    '''
    (float) -> float
    f must be increasing
    '''
    return x**2

def find(v, n):
    '''
    (float, int) -> int
    Returns k in [0:n]
    such that |f(k) - v| is minimum
    '''
    
    min_index = 0
    
    for k in range(n):
        if f(k) >= v:
            min_index = k
            return min_index

    return -1
```

For the case find(5, 10) it returns the wrong index (it should be '2', but it returns '3'). However, when i call find(2, 10), it gives me the correct answer.

What is happening here?

Observation: Cannot use search algorithms such as binary search and etc

Thank you

Comment: Is this the kind of function you can binary search?

Comment: No, you should use the fact that the first k such that f(k) > v solves the problem

Comment: Then I guess you're done.

Comment: it does not work always, check the description

Comment: @dankal444 but why the current code does not return the best option at first?

Comment: You know what the vertical bars in "|f(k)-v|" mean ... I assume.  If not, look up modulus or absolute value; e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value

Comment: *"No, you should use the fact that the first k such that f(k) > v solves the problem "* - It doesn't.   See above.

Comment: @StephenC that solves the problem indeed, why not? the absolute value function does not invalidate this idea

Comment: @Lucas Absolute value ***does*** invalidate your search implementation.

Comment: Why do you say "it should be '2'"?

Comment: *"when i call find(2, 10), it gives me the correct answer"* - That's not true, it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your task is to minimize the absolute deviation from target. What you’re actually doing is finding the first positive deviation. A negative deviation can have a smaller magnitude than the first positive deviation, in which case you will return the wrong answer for the task.

If your target value is 5, f(2) -> 4 and f(3) -> 9. The index k==3 yields the first outcome greater than 5, which meets your program’s criteria but ignores absolute value. |f(2) - 5| -> 1, while |f(3) - 5| -> 4. Since 1 < 4, f(2) minimizes your objective function and is the correct answer.

You will get the wrong answer for many target values if your program ignores the absolute value of the deviations from target.

Comment: I'd say they're not really "ignoring" the absolute value. If they did, and thus minimized f(k)-v instead, they'd simply always return 0.

Comment: @KellyBundy True, but they’re certainly ignoring the concept of “closeness” to target and getting the wrong answer by ignoring that the idea of closeness is based on absolute value. They’d have the same problem if they used squared deviation from target rather than absolute deviation from target. The point is that they can’t just ignore the mandated definition of distance from target.

Comment: How do i fix it @pjs ?

Comment: @Lucas You asked “what is happening here?”, and I’ve explained that. I assume this is a homework assignment, and as a retired prof I decline to write the solution for you, but I’ll point you to MrSmith42’s sentence that begins “Finally…” as a fix.

Comment: @pjs This is not homework assignment, but you can certainly assume whatever you want. Thanks for the help, it was clarifying anyway

Comment: @Lucas Okay, I've gotta ask - if this isn't a homework problem, why the requirement to not use binary search? Is it because your f(x) isn't necessarily convex?

Comment: @pjs I am an undergrad in mathematics who likes programming and i am just trying to use some math fact to do it more efficiently without using those famous/common algorithms

Comment: @Lucas You're a *math undergrad* and didn't see the issue?

Comment: i saw the issue, i cannot fix it

Comment: @Lucas My mistake then, *"What is happening here?"* didn't sound to me like you did.

Comment: English is not even my first language, i am trying my best to communicate @KellyBundy, but anyway i dont need someone to make me feel bad for being an undergrad and not know a certain thing, i am trying my best to learn, put things into perspective please and be more respectful, you know nothing about my background, what i know/dont know

Comment: @KellyBundy I am asking here to learn and think, not to be judged by what i should know or not, you should know that, you are a more experienced user than me

Answer (score 2):

f which is increasing. So the minimum of `|f(k)-v|` is where `f(k)-v=0` (*or if f(0)-v > 0 the minimum is at 0*)

So find the integer where `f(k-1)-v < 0` and `f(k)-v >= 0`.
This can be done by binary search.

Finally you need to decide if `|f(k-1)-v| < |f(k)-v|` and return either `k-1` or `k`

---

P.s.
If you know (or can calculate) `f'(k)` (the derived from f(k) ) you could also use the [Newton-Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) instead of binary search.

Comment: I am not allowed to use binary search

Comment: Given that the most efficient solution is a form of binary search, I very much doubt that.  What the requirements probably say is that you are not allowed to used a pre-existing binary search **library function**.  Binary search is an algorithm ...

Comment: It might even be the case, but i still dont know why my code does not work

Comment: @Lucas: This is an opportunity to learn about debugging. This way you find out where your code behaves different from what you expected. But 'Why is my code not working as expected?' is a different question and should not be mixed up here.

Comment: where should i ask it @MrSmith42?

Comment: @Lucas: After trying to find it out yourself during debugging you can post the Question here on stackoverflow. But as I understood your question, you were primary searching for a solution to the question 'Find efficient algorithm...' and not 'Why is my code behaving differently to what I expected it to do?'